# Spring boot 2 accessing Oauth2 secured resources

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0

We are trying to migrate our `Spring Boot 1` application to `Spring Boot 2.` This app needs to access a `oAuth2` secured resource. We were using the `OAuth2RestTemplate` which now does not work anymore.

We have a `client_credentials` `grant-type,` and I struggle to see how to use it in `Spring Boot 2`.

Our app does not need any `authentication` itself, but the resource it accesses uses it. It seems all examples and explanations use the `oAuth` token of the client accessing it to access upstream resources - which is not something I would like to do.

Comment: can you explain what error are you getting or what exactly is not working ?

Comment: Well, there is no more Oauth2Resttemplate, and I cannot see how to get the RestTemplate to use OAuth2.

Comment: What do you mean by *there is no more Oauth2Resttemplate*? `OAuth2RestTemplate`  isn't part of Spring Boot at all. It is part of Spring Security OAuth2.

Comment: However, Spring Security 5 supports its own way. It is better to use the new way.

Comment: Yes, I looked at https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html5/#oauth2client and couldn't figure out how to make it work. The example does not compile, and then they are back to using it to secure the app with it, not authenticating to another app. Do you have any examples you could point me to? I am surely missing something.